# Surface of Revolution with 3D surface

Tags: mathematics

I have to use this function to get a Surface of Revolution (homework).

```
newVertex = (oldVertex.y, someFunc1(oldVertex.x, oldVertex.y), someFunc2(oldVertex.x, oldVertex.y));
```

As far as I know (FIXME) Surface of Revolution means rotations of a (2D)curve around an axis in 3D.
But this vertex computing gives a 3D plane (FIXME again :D), so rotation of this isn't
obvious.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Not quite sure what the question is exactly, but a 'Surface of Revolution' is also known as 3D Lathe. Here is an interactive demo - http://www.fisme.uu.nl/toepassingen/00182/toepassing_wisweb.en.html

Comment: Its a 2D curve rotated around the X axis.
But this function is not a 2D curve.

Comment: This is not Game Development.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the 2D "curve" is given as a polyline with `oldVertex` vertices. Rotating the curve around an axis should result in appropriate 3D vertices where each old vertex creates a loop of new vertices given an angle-step.

The other possibility I imaging is rotating given 3D vertices according to their x/y components, ignoring z. That would involve some dot- and crossproducts but you example code doesn't make a lot of sense in that case.

Are you sure you got all those x/y/z parts right?

Comment: Yeah, I have X, Y, Y; But I still don't understand what to do.
The mentioned function is not a curve. Its a shader used on a plane's vertices. No idai, where to do a rotation.

Comment: Oh I got it. I don't have to rotate to begin with.